# Https requests are not working in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

I have an asp.net website which is hosted on windows azure. The application is working very fine. I have configure self-signed certificates in IIS of windows azure. I have also configured the IIS bindings to use https(port 443). But, now my website is not working with https.

Note: I am also not seeing any screen about invalid certificates. The browser says the site not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure [HTTPS IN Input endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff795779.aspx) with that certificate? If you just configured the self signed cert on the IIS in Azure Web Role instances, it will never work. Because your service definition has no HTTPS endpoint configured, thus the load balancer will not route any https traffic to your instances.

You may read [this blog post](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/03/windows-azure-basics-part-2-of.html), to get to know how Windows Azure Networking works.

Comment: This seems to be missing for me. Thanks, I will check

Answer (score 1):

I have written a details blog about how to configure your Windows Azure application using HTTPS endpoint using SSL Certificate, from scratch as below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/28/complete-solution-adding-ssl-certificate-with-windows-azure-application.aspx

Comment: Very nice Avkash. Thanks for sharing.